# Change updateurl after publish

Tags: vsto, clickonce

There's a ton of questions on this topic, which don't seem to answer the specific use case that I have.

I have a VSTO for Outlook and I want to be able to change the update url after it's been published. Once it's built and published to my local machine I'd like to use a script or tool to change the update url so that I can essentially build once, deploy everywhere (like I do with my web apps).

**NOTE:** I'm not asking to change the publish url on an application that's already been installed on a clients machine.

My CI server will build and publish and then as part of a deployment process the idea is deploy it to the Dev environment under the dev update url and then deploy it to Staging under the update url for staging etc.

The answer at this link doesn't work because my output doesn't contain a *.application file http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5309f67e-efe4-40b4-b937-aed18cf87155/clickonce-change-deployment-url-after-publish

Here's what the publish folder contains

[image]
And inside "Application Files"
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is amazingly easy. All you have to do is update the setup.exe through the command line. Really wish this information was available on MSDN.

```
setup.exe /url= http://myserverhostname/
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/633a284c-6485-4266-a6c5-01055e43dcf4/clickonce-with-bootstraper-setupexe-need-to-change-url-without-any-build?forum=winformssetup

To see what options are available to you just type `setup.exe /?`

[image]

Comment: So what if people directly install the `vsto` instead of the bootstraper? They won't give anything about the updated URL in it...

Comment: I'm assuming if you provided the VSTO directly to the client than the whole concept of updates doesn't even apply anymore. The whole purpose the bootstrapper is to reach out to some URL, find the VSTO which has all of the necessary information (current version etc) and then the bootstrapper can pull down whatever files it wants.

Comment: If the client version is 390 and the bootstrapper checks for an update   it will go to the specified url, find the vsto, download it, inspect it and if the new vsto version is higher (lets say 391) than the current then the bootstrapper will find the new files and install them.

Comment: *"Really wish this information was available on MSDN."* - it is, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/h4k032e1.aspx). The same page says, that the `setup.exe` *"is responsible for installing these prerequisites before your application runs"*. So the concept still applies. It's just about the prerequisites, not the updates!

Comment: @Herdo Great find, unfortunately it was buried. I don't know how many "vsto change update url after publish", "clickonce change update url" etc searches I did without finding this information.